# NodeJS Express DynamicView Helper with an http request

Tags: asynchronous, node.js

I hava a node.js app running on express with a dynamicViewHelper that hits an http service with http.request.  Unfortunately, when I try to do this, because the http  request is asynchronous and the function calling it is not, the page just renders before the http request is finished and I end up with undefined on my page.

I am basically looking for a way to put an asynchronous action (the http request), inside of a dynamic view helper which gets rendered out on the page.  I know I can't just turn it into a synchronous function, so I am looking for another way to get that dynamic data to the view.

Also, is there a way to cache the data that is returned from an http.request()?  I don't want to put it on the session, but I want any further requests made to the exact same URL to possibly be cached...  Not as big of a deal as the first part of my question, though.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  I'll just load it in my route so that `res.render()` isn't called until the request is done.

Comment: Hi Alberto, can you explain how you did it? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: I can't remember exactly what I did.  The problem was that the view helpers were taking too long and thus the page returned the request before they were done.  Take a look at some of the express source--it's really not that complicated.